# Project Euler 17

Tags: python

This problem is Project Euler problem 17. Refer here for the question: http://projecteuler.net/problem=17.

> If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
>
> If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?
>
> **NOTE:** Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

The output should come out to be 21124 but according to the following code, the output is 21112. I have tried to find an error in this code, please help!

```
dict = {} #empty dictionary
dict[0]=0
dict[1]=3
dict[2]=3
dict[3]=5
dict[4]=4
dict[5]=4
dict[6]=3
dict[7]=5
dict[8]=5
dict[9]=4
dict[10]=3
dict[11]=6
dict[12]=6
dict[13]=8
dict[14]=8
dict[15]=7
dict[16]=7
dict[17]=9
dict[18]=8
dict[19]=8
dict[20]=6
dict[30]=6
dict[40]=5
dict[50]=5
dict[60]=5
dict[70]=7
dict[80]=6
dict[90]=6
dict[100]=7
dict[1000]=11
sum = 0
#sumation for single digit numbers
for i in range(1,11):
        sum += dict[i]
        
#summation for numbers less than 20
for i in range(11,21):
        sum += dict[i]
        
#for sumation upto hundred terms
for i in range(21,100):
        j = i
        sum += (dict[(j - j%10)])
        sum += dict[j%10]

sum+=dict[1]+dict[100]

#for numbers from 101 to 999
for i in range(101,1000):
        print("sum = "+str(sum)+" i = "+str(i))
        sum += dict[int(i/100)]+dict[100]
        sum += dict[i%100-(i%10)]+dict[i%10]
        sum += len("and")
        
sum += dict[1000]
print("Total = %d"%sum)
```

Comment: `range(1,11)` is the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, not the single-digit numbers. Similarly for `range(11,21)`, which goes up to `20`, not `19`. You should not name your variable `dict`, because this shadows the built-in dictionary constructor, which is named `dict`. I don't think either of these issues are causing your bugs, but you should take note of these things anyway.

Comment: Why don't you try your code with a smaller set that you can manually count, e.g., 820-830?  Check out http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html# to step through your code and see the output at each step.  It was invaluable to me when I was first learning programming (and still is very helpful to me now!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in numbers such as `914` which you'll count as "9 100 and 10 4" (Nine houndred and ten four) which does not have the same amount of letters as "9 100 and 14" (Nine houndred and fourteen).

This problem arises from

```
sum += dict[int(i/100)]+dict[100]
sum += dict[i%100-(i%10)]+dict[i%10]
```

where for such `i` as `i=914` the computation in the second line goes like this

```
i%100-(i%10) == 914%100 - 914%10 == 14 - 4 == 10
```

Furthermore, are numbers like 900 not called "Nine hundred and" but you're code does add the `len("and")` even when `i%100 == 0`.

**You will therefore need to handle multiples of 100 and numbers in their teens differently.**

As a hint for similar exercices, I'd recommend you store the actual string in the dictionary (e.g `dict[13] = 'thirteen')` and then use `len(dict[13])` to get the number. That way you are safe from silly counting mistakes and can verify the computation more easily. After all, if you spot your code claiming that `914` is written out as "Nine hundred and ten four" it's easier to realize that something's off.

Comment: He also counts e.g. `200` as `'two hundred and'`